# YouTube Player's events don't work at UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I want to play movies automatically and go next movie automatically on UIWebView. I embeded YouTube Player on UIWebView and use some [YouTube Player API for iFrame](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ja) snippets, but they didn't work well.

HTML is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  var tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
      height: "390",
      width: "640",
      videoId: "UqFvrjhbO8c",
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      document.location = "api://didEndedMovie";
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the movie ended, I want the webview to load `api://didEndedMovie`. Then, WebView delegate will receive loaded event, and will call bellow delegate method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (!_htmlTemplate) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubePlayer" ofType:@"html"];
    _htmlTemplate = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:_htmlTemplate];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

// if delegate received requests like "api://*", this view controller
// will not move to other views.  

if ([requestString rangeOfString:@"api://"].location == NSNotFound) {
    return YES;
}

// called when the movie ended
if ([requestString isEqualToString:@"api://didEndedMovie"]) {
    NSLog(@"didEndedMovie");
}

return NO;
}
```

But, javascript doesn't work... The events `onReady` and `onStateChange` are not fired.

On browser, this javascript works well.

Why are not the events fired?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question and I don't know if you still need help, so I'll be succinct.

Instead of using [webView loadHTMLString:baseURL], use [webView loadRequest]. The loadRequest method is able to fully load the referenced YouTube iframe javascript and you're able to interact with the iframe api. Then you'll see the onReady and onStateChange events fire. You'll also be able to call the cueing functions and other things. Let me know if that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: When i Use  [webView loadRequest]. than my video is not working.

Comment: loadRequest is for loading remote resources, while loadHTMLString is for local html in your app.

Comment: you can loadRequest a local path